# reach a specific index in a structered matrix with the function find matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, struct, find

I receive this error
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array
Error in perturb_method (line 136)
[j,k]=find(pop(i).mat.p==x)
pop is a population of structred matix (mat) i want to knew the indices  of  a specific elemnet in the part p of matrix mat, how can i process please?

Comment: Hi Samia, can you provide us with a bit more detail about your data structure? An example of what `pop` and its child elements look like?

Comment: NP = 10;
for i =1:NP
    for j=1:matR
        for k=1:matC
           
            MAT{j,k}.s=randi(8);
            MAT{j,k}.p=randi(16);
            
        end
    end
    pop(i).mat=MAT;

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you forgot to take into account that `pop(i).mat` is a cell array. The following should work:

```
% Create data structure
NP=10;
matR=4;
matC=4;
for i=1:NP
  for j=1:matR
    for k=1:matC
      MAT{j,k}.s=randi(8);
      MAT{j,k}.p=randi(16);
    end
  end
  pop(i).mat=MAT;
end

% Find `x' in data
x=5;
for i=1:NP
  q=[pop(i).mat{:}];
  [j,k]=ind2sub(size(pop(i).mat),find([q.p]==x)), %we could use reshape() here instead
end
```

However, you might want to consider simplifying your program, if at all possible:

```
% Create data structure
NP=10;
matR=4;
matC=4;
s=randi(8,[matR matC NP]);
p=randi(16,[matR matC NP]);

% Find `x' in data
x=5;
for i=1:NP
  [j,k]=find(p(:,:,i)==x),
end
```